# Laravel "Next ErrorException: A non well formed numeric value encountered" php-7.4

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-500

When I try to open the site, the HTTP 500 error appears, and the Laravel log shows: "A non well formed numeric value encountered"

Here's a value of `$sec` before casting `intval(($sec / 60) % 60)`.
Value is `60.316000` and type of this value: `string`.

Here is the content of the index.blade.php file: https://pastebin.com/Cv8hsndU

Here is the content of the helpers.php file: https://pastebin.com/1TSY2rTC

Any idea how can I fix this, in file `index.blade.php` where this function called (strings 29,50,86,122,150), code that's call it looks like this:

```
@if($recomment != NULL)
            @foreach($recomment as $result)
                <?php $video_categories = get_video_form_cat($result->ID) ?>
                @if(count($video_categories)>0)
                    <h2>Recommended Category For You <a style="text-decoration: none" href="{{URL('categories/')}}/{{$result->ID}}.{{$result->post_name}}.html"><span>-{{$result->title_name}}</span></a></h2>
                    <div class="row content-image">
                         @foreach($video_categories as $result)
                            <?php $rating=GetRatingVideo($result->string_Id);?>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3  image-left">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="col_img">
                                        <span class="hd">HD</span>
                                        <a href="{{URL('watch')}}/{{$result->string_Id.'/'.$result->post_name}}.html">
                                            <img src="{{$result->getImageUrl($result->poster)}}" alt="{{$result->title_name}}" height="177" />
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="position_text">
                                            <p class="icon-like"></p>
                                            <p class="percent">{{floor($rating['percent_like'])}}%</p>
                                            <p class="time_minimute">{{sec2hms($result->duration)}}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <h3><a href="{{URL('watch')}}/{{$result->string_Id.'/'.$result->post_name}}.html">{{str_limit($result->title_name,30)}}</a></h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        @endif
```

Here's function that's causing this error (helpers.php):

```
   function sec2hms ($sec, $padHours = false)
         {
            $hms = "";
            $hours = intval(intval($sec) / 3600);
            if($hours > 0){
              $hms .= ($padHours)? str_pad($hours, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT). ':': $hours. ':';  
            }
            $minutes = intval(($sec / 60) % 60);
            $hms .= str_pad($minutes, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT). ':';
            $seconds = intval($sec % 60);
            $hms .= str_pad($seconds, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            return $hms;
        }
```

Here's a full error message from Laravel log:

```
Next ErrorException: A non well formed numeric value encountered (View: /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/resources/views/home/index.blade.php) in /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/app/Helper/helpers.php:35
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(44): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->handleViewException()
#1 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(58): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath()
#2 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(135): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get()
#3 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(106): Illuminate\View\View->getContents()
#4 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(80): Illuminate\View\View->renderContents()
#5 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(51): Illuminate\View\View->render()
#6 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php(198): Illuminate\Http\Response->setContent()
#7 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1229): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response->__construct()
#8 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(112): Illuminate\Routing\Router->prepareResponse()
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#10 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(139): call_user_func()
#11 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#12 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func()
#13 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(114): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then()
#14 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(68): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack()
#15 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(203): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()
#16 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(134): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runWithCustomDispatcher()
#17 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(708): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
#18 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#19 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(139): call_user_func()
#20 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#21 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func()
#22 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(710): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then()
#23 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(674): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#24 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(635): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#25 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(236): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch()
#26 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}()
#27 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(139): call_user_func()
#28 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(50): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#29 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(31): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
#30 [internal function]: App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
#31 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array()
#32 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#33 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()
#34 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array()
#35 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(62): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#36 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle()
#37 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array()
#38 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#39 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()
#40 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array()
#41 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#42 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle()
#43 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array()
#44 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#45 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle()
#46 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array()
#47 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#48 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func()
#49 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then()
#50 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(87): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#51 /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/index.php(96): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle()
#52 {main}
```

Comment: Please post the full error message

Comment: @marks done, I add more details to my quastion

Comment: You are calling `sec2hms($result->duration)` and as the error suggests in line 35 the error occurs when casting `intval(($sec / 60) % 60)`, where `$sec` is `$result->duration`. As `intval` casts from double to integer I assume `$sec` is not numeric. Try `var_dump($sec)` before line 35 and see what the type is. At best with a `try` block around line 35 and the `var_dump` in the respective following `catch` to ensure you are printing the one that throws. From there backtrack why you have an invalid types in your data. Could be wrong database definitions, wrong observers, anything.

Comment: By the way https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php might do what you need

Comment: @marks here's a value of `$sec` before casting `intval(($sec / 60) % 60)` value is `60.316000` . So whats wrong. Thats a numeric value.

Comment: And what variable type does var_dump show you?

Comment: @marks I use `\Log::debug($sec);`. I have no idea how to use var_dump because http 500 error.

Comment: Put the var dump in your log statement or do `var_dump($sec); die();` before the line that throws.

Comment: @marks How to put it to log statement? `var_dump($sec); die();` cant be used because part of code where error causing thats a helper, not a main page.

Comment: Log::debug(gettype($sec))

Comment: @marks So yeah thats a string

`[2021-03-19 17:33:46] local.DEBUG: string  
[2021-03-19 17:33:46] local.DEBUG: 60.316000`

But how can i fix this, in file `index.blade.php` where this function called (29,50,86,122,150 strings), code thats call it looks like this: 

`<div class="position_text">
         <p class="icon-like"></p>
          <p class="percent">{{floor($rating['percent_like'])}}%</p>
          <p class="time_minimute">{{sec2hms($result->duration)}}</p>
</div>`

You can view full code here: https://pastebin.com/Cv8hsndU

Comment: Depends on where the data for `$result->duration` comes from. It can be because you declared it a string in the database, can be because you do something like ` + ''` somewhere before: You need to backtrack where the data comes from to find out why it is a string. A simple workaround would be to cast the input of your function to a double. But that would not be the real solution, just dirty workaround